# Django Error on django-admin startproject

Tags: django, pip, django-admin, virtualenv

I try this command:

```
$ virtualenv .venv
$ sourse .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) $ pip3 install django
```

1. The last command installed the django3 on the whole system while the virtual machine was active and should only be installed on the virtual machine. why??
2. I tried `django-admin stratproject mysite`, but I received this error:

```
Command 'django-admin' not found, but can be installed with:
    sudo apt install python-django-common
```

so, I try `sudo apt install python-django-common`. Then again try `django-admin stratproject mysite` and resived error: `Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django`.

**how I can solve this problem??**

Comment: When you run ```pip freeze``` on your terminal. Do you see Django installed or on the list?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a Python path. If you have, you can enter the Python terminal when you write Python. You can see the installed libraries by typing pip freeze.

Answer (score 0):

The Django is not added in your python path , if you still want to run your code go to python directory and then run the django-admin command.

Go to the folder where your python is installed and open terminal there 
after that run your command

```
django-admin startproject test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`pip`**`install django` instead of `pip3 install django` in virtualenv.

---

By running `virtualenv .venv` you have created local python environment with current default system version of python (i.e. on older distributions this might be python 2.7)

While activating virtual environment, it replaces some ENV variables to allow python to address this local environment, but not system one.

`pip` is one of them. `pip` inside virtualenv points to virtualenv's pip. Virtualenv might not redefine `pip3` command - this is only needed system-wide, cause you may have many different versions of python in the system at the same time. And as far as virtualenv has only one version of python / packages inside - where is no need for it to redefine `pip3`.

Running `django-admin startproject test` inside virtualenv uses virtualenv's python packages, and if there is none, it may actually use system-wide packages, but it depends on the options virtualenv was created with (use system pacakges), PATH variables etc.

Also, try not to install or rely on system-wide packages - use virtuelnv.

Using virtualenv is good, and there is a lot of helpers to ease - pipenv, virtualenwrapper etc

Answer (score 0):

Just run this in the command line.

```
apt-get install python3-django
```

Hope this will solve your problem.